# Can't click on button in shadow-dom

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, shadow-dom

I'm trying to scrape a dynamic site (https://app.shaggyowl.com/accesso-titolare/index.html)  with selenium and python. I found a workaround to insert username and password but I'm not able to click the button (below).

```py
text_editing_host_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "flt-text-editing-host")
script = """
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
input.setAttribute("autocorrect", "on");
input.setAttribute("class", "flt-text-editing transparentTextEditing");
input.style.cssText = "forced-color-adjust: none; white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 1; color: transparent; background: transparent; caret-color: transparent; outline: none; border: none; resize: none; text-shadow: none; overflow: hidden; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; font: 16px Poppins, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; width: 280px; height: 22px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 202.5, 335.3);";
arguments[0].appendChild(input);
"""
driver.execute_script(script, text_editing_host_element)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > flutter-view > flt-text-editing-host > input').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > flutter-view > flt-text-editing-host').send_keys(
    'Username')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > flutter-view > flt-text-editing-host').send_keys(Keys.TAB)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > flutter-view > flt-text-editing-host > input:nth-child(2)').send_keys(
    'Password')
```

I searched for Shadow-dom and dynamic sites with js but I didn't find the solution and I would be happy if someone could give me a suggestion.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button is actually a part of flutter app and is rendered inside only on click.

I don't see any sign that it is rendered is `shadow-dom`, but if it doesn't exist until action, there is not direct way to locate it.

However, after focusing password input and typing password, you can click on it by offset from password field via `ActionChains`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

link = "https://app.shaggyowl.com/accesso-titolare/index.html"
driver.get(link)
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'flutter-view')))
action_chains.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'flt-text-editing-host')))
action_chains.send_keys('Username').perform()
time.sleep(1)
action_chains.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
action_chains.send_keys('Password').perform()
input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=password]')
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(input, 10, 100).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @Yaroslavm! I did in that way and it's working!

Comment: @Federico I'm glad to help. Can you, plz, mark this answer as correct if it resolves your issue?